# Unable to captureStream from a video element with salesforce content as the video source

Tags: apex, error, files, cors, video

We're looking to stream content in a HTML  tag through a video chat service, TokBox. This content is currently housed in Salesforce Files, and we're trying to access this content via the "streamCapture()" function in a Visualforce page. The error we're getting is this:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'captureStream' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Cannot capture from element with cross-origin data.

It looks like there is a CORS issue between our page `[sandboxName].visual.force.com` and the location of the File `[sandboxName].content.force.com`, and we're looking for any possible solutions to work around this error.

Here is a code snippet showing our problem.

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
            <video id="testVideo" src="/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/0684C000000TgYCQA0" type="video/mp4" controls="controls" height="100" >
            </video>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               var streamCapture = document.getElementById("testVideo").captureStream();
            </script>
</apex:page>
```